# link:visited doesn't work with sibling combinator

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I need to change style of neighboring element when link is visited:

```
a:visited + div { color: #000 }
```

This does not work. What can I do to get the styling I need?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using css.. however you can do that using jquery

Comment: Can i do that using js??? if i can, can you get link with doc or example

Comment: "Browsers limits the styles that can be set for a:visited links, due to security issues."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find anything in the Specs, that expicitely prohibits the sibling combinator from working with this pseudo class, however:

The `:visited` pseudo-class is a special case, since it can be abused to infringe the users privacy. That's why browser are allowed to treat `:visited` differently. To my knowledge, browsers simply lie about the styling of visited links, while still applying the styles - technically they would be allowed to not apply `:visited` styling at all. I *suppose*, that most vendors just decided, to not apply styling to sibling combinators <sup>( Since this is only speculation on my side, if somebody has a concrete source for this, please confirm.)</sup>.

See the note in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited)

> Note: It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the user's consent.
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

```js
console.log(`Browser is lying about  the color of the i element - should be olive, but is ${window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("a i")).color} (red) instead.`);
```

```css
a{
  color:red;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:20px;
}
a:visited{
  color:#bada55;
}
a:visited ~ div{
  color:LightGoldenRodYellow !important;
}
a span{
  color:RebeccaPurple;
}
a:visited i{
  color:Olive;
}
a:last-of-type{
  color:hotpink;
}
a:last-of-type + div{
  color:MediumSeaGreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Is red while not visited! <span>Is always RebeccaPurple!</span> <i>Should be olive once link is visited!</i></a>
<a href="#">Will be #bada55 when visited!</a>
<a href="#">Will be hotpink!</a>
<div>Should be LightGoldenRodYellow, but is MediumSeaGreen!</div>
```